# How to send MIDI Control Change Message from Python?

Tags: python

I would like to know how can i send MIDI Control Change messages from a Python script to an application called rakarrack, which receives MIDI messages to change volumes, turn on/off FX's, etc. All this done via JACK/ALSA.

At this point i just try with the library [python-rtmidi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-rtmidi/) (the code i wrote is based on the example provided there), but when i try to send the messages, rakarrack doesn't do anything. I think because is not receiving anything. I already check the Preference in the application and the MIDI In device (which is created from Python) is listed as 'rtmidi' and selected.

```
import time
import rtmidi

midiout = rtmidi.MidiOut()
available_ports = midiout.get_ports()

if available_ports:
    midiout.open_port(0)
else:
    midiout.open_virtual_port("My virtual output")

control = [0x74, 116, 124] 
midiout.send_message(control)

del midiout
```

As you can see, I'm trying to send one control message  [0x74, 116, 124] , I took those numbers from here: http://rakarrack.sourceforge.net/midiic.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I need to send a "Chan 1 Control/Mode Change" message as the first byte, which is "0xb0", then 0x74 which is the control that i want change, and finally the value "124", which is turn on/off FX:

```
control = [0xb0, 0x74, 124]
```

Comment: Stumbled across the same problem. The `rtmidi` lib has constants for those. You can `from rtmidi.midiconstants import CONTROL_CHANGE` which equals to `0xB0`, for example. There are many more useful constants in there.